# Unity - does the current version generate native code or not?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

Here I can see that Unity documentation says that it is 50% slower than  native code: http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Script_compilation_28Advanced29.html

Here it says that there is an IL2CPP compiler, that obtains c++ code which is compiled into native code. So is it now creating native code, or is it 50% slower? :)
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/06/an-introduction-to-ilcpp-internals/
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/20/the-future-of-scripting-in-unity/

Comment: The two aren't mutually exclusive, since IL2CPP may or may not outperform the JIT.

Comment: @SteveJessop at least we can agree, that these our talking about different methodologies of obtaining the executable, right?

Comment: Are you missing a link for the second paragraph when you say *Here it says that...*?

Comment: @Narek: oh definitely, your question stands as "does Unity actually use IL2CPP or not?". I just thought it might be optimistic to presume that IL2CPP achieves the full performance of whatever it was they benchmarked the .NET code against in order to deduce that it was 50% slower :-)

Comment: It's more complicated than what you're asking, and I really wouldn't bother about it. It's all-but impossible to realistically compare the speed of the entire Unity pipeline, to native either iOS or Android. Those speed comparisons are completely ridiculous because the Unity pipeline just has a staggering amount of overhead which simply is not in the pipeline in native apps.  The only way those speed comparisons could even vaguely mean anything is if (totally bizarrely) as an exercise you wrote say a math test, which did *not at all even use* the two rendering pipelines, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation from Unity you referenced is pretty old, and even at the time it is written, I would really wonder about those performance numbers. In general, performance is much more complex to measure and report than one number like 50% can express.

If you want to learn more about IL2CPP, check out this [blog post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/06/an-introduction-to-ilcpp-internals/) series.

Based on our benchmarks at Unity, we're seeing better performance for script-bound code with IL2CPP than with the Unity version of Mono. You can find one benchmark we have published [here](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/10/07/benchmarking-unity-performance-in-webgl/).

There are a few caveats to keep in mind though:

- Unity uses an old version of the Mono runtime (circa 2011). Newer versions are better - and we are working on upgrading the runtime now.
- Most game code is not script-bound, it is usually GPU-bound.
- The generated C++ code is still providing the safety of a managed language, so it makes array bounds checks, for example.
- The performance difference between the Mono AOT and the IL2CPP compilers will vary based on the platform. On some platforms, the Mono AOT compiler produces machine code as well as a C++ compiler. On other platforms this is not the case.

Comment: This is a terrific answer.